# ClickHouse, How to modify values at insertion?

Tags: sql, columnstore, clickhouse, bigdata

Is there a way to do this ? At first glance it should be possible with DEFAULT but I can't figure the syntax. Basically what I want to do is have a column that looks like this:

my_string string DEFAULT operation(my_original_string)

Without permanently storing "my_original_string" in the table. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using batch insert over VALUES format with use functions

```
INSERT INTO table 
VALUES (any_available_function_name('my_original_value')),
       (any_available_function_name2('my_original_value2'))
```

see available function here https://clickhouse.yandex/reference_en.html#Functions2

Comment: That is indeed an option, but what I want is sort of a "rule" at insertion, no matter where the data is coming from or how I'm inserting it. If that is however not an option this might help

Comment: use MATERIALIZED or VIRTUAL columns, but it's possible only with storing permanently "my_original_string" in the table.